Why are EXIF data timestamps wrong on many iPhone 15 photos?
I took over two thousand pictures while on vacation in Europe with my partner's iPhone 15 Pro. Going through them now, I see that the timestamps (as stored in the 'EXIF' metadata section of the image) on hundreds of them are completely wrong - they are off by exactly 9 hours, which happens to be the time zone difference between my home in California and the photo location in Europe.  Examples (these pictures were all taken in the same general location at roughly the same time and are clearly sequential):

IMG_2011 - EXIF timestamp 02:19:45 (I was asleep at 02:19 local time,
so this is obviously wrong)

IMG_2012 - EXIF timestamp 11:25:39  (this is the correct local time)

IMG_2013 - EXIF timestamp 02:25:58 (taken 19 seconds after the
previous image but with wrong timestamp)

IMG_2014 - EXIF timestamp 11:28:09 (taken ~2 minutes after the
previous image) with correct timestamp


All three EXIF timestamps are equally wrong, on the 'bad' images - DateTime, DateTimeOriginal, and DateTimeDigitized.
Of particular interest are images IMG_2012 and IMG_2013 - they were taken from the same spot, just 19 seconds apart, but show timestamps 9 hours apart.
The GPS location of all the photos is correct - so it's not as if there was no GPS signal at some points in time causing the camera to think it was back in CA. These are outdoor photos so again, no GPS issues.
The EXIF timestamps are very important to me for various reasons so this is a big issue. I do have EXIF tools to correct the timestamps, but it is a terribly tedious procedure.
I did closely analyze the full EXIF data, and I did notice one thing - for the images with 'correct' timestamps, they show OffsetTime, OffsetTimeOriginal and OffsetTimeDigital as +2:00; and for the images with the wrong timestamps, they show OffsetTime, OffsetTimeOriginal and OffsetTimeDigital as -7:00.  I'm guessing these are relative to GMT/UTC, as Spain is currently UTC+2 and California is UTC-7.  So something is causing the iPhone to mark half the images with the wrong offset for some reason.
Here's a composite screenshot of the two images discussed above (screenshots from the iPhone) that were taken 19 seconds apart. As you can see, the image on the left is showing 11:25am, while the image on the right is showing 2:25am - 9 hours off.  Interestingly, they sort correctly on the iPhone despite the time issues.

And here's a snapshot of the EXIF data for the above two images:

and a snapshot of the GPS data portion of the EXIF data:

The "GPSTimeStamp" entry - approx. 9:25 - is the correct 'UTC' time for both pictures.
I'm curious to understand how this could have happened, but I guess I also need to find a way to correct the 'bad' versions.
Minor update - the first ~1,600 photos on the trip (taken over a 2 week period) have accurate metadata. The first 'bad' timestamp was IMG_1800, taken Sep-20-2024, and was part of a sequence of images taken inside a church in Montserrat - no obvious difference from previous image.  For the remainder of the vacation (2 days, approx 200 images), the image metadata was 'mostly bad' with occasional 'good' metadata, but a few sequences of 'mostly good' metadata with occasional 'bad' metadata. The oddest thing is that the 'good' and 'bad' images were often taken in the same location / similar time, which rules out environmental / positional issues.
Now that we are back in the US, I have very few new pictures to analyze and the everything appears to be back to normal (but we won't know until we next travel).
UPDATE - here's a snapshot of a windows file manager window, showing the 'date taken' information for a sequence of images taken throughout the day (I realize windows file manager isn't always the most reliable indicator but in this case I can confirm the 'date taken' column corresponds to the exif data in the files).

The images shown are in chronological sequence. Img_1914 and 1915 have timestamps circa 3am (I was sleeping at that time). Img_1916 has a timestamp 12:24pm and is correct. Then img_1917 goes back to circa 3am, and the images all the way to img_1931 are too early by 9 hours. Then img_1932 has the correct time of 3:15pm, then the images after that are bad again, until img_1939, which shows the correct time of 7:44pm.  The images then stay 'good' until Img_1951, which jumps back 9 hours.  The 'good' and 'bad' images were in many cases taken in the exact same location, and ALL images have the correct GPS time.

Was your phone set to adjust time zones per the cellular carrier? Did you load an eSIM at any point or disable cellular service to avoid international roaming charges? Those typically can cause unexpected zone changes.

@bmike - we did disable cellular at times on the early portion of the trip but the problems started when we reached our last destination (Barcelona) and we made no changes to cellular settings or time zones there. I added a summary at the end of the question. No new eSIMs loaded.  The key thing that rules out your concerns is that the errors occurred between two images taken 19 seconds apart from the same location (multiple instances of this, one given in the question).  I'm certain no changes were made between those two shots!

Wow - that is so strange... Your details are most excellent and I'll come back with a better answer than the "boilerplate" here's how to fix this if you can't use exiftool or another scripted solution. In this case, I would submit feedback to Apple in case they're chasing this bug and you're the person that has the evidence to let them fix it ...

Off the top of my head, without any research, perhaps the cell signal was weak, and your phone dropped the connection when you changed orientation to take the next shot, and iOS fell back to your ‘home’ timezone? When the phone reconnected, it picked up the correct timezone.  Just a thought.

@IconDaemon - weak cell signal is always a possibility, but the pattern of 'failures' is so unusual.  We were traveling 'overseas' (Barcelona, relative to our home base of California)  but I added Verizon's international plan for the month (as opposed to adding a second eSIM).  We traveled for over 3 weeks; the first two weeks, we were all over the place, on a cruise ship, in over 5 countries, and the problem never occurred once.  But all of a sudden, after 2 days in Barcelona, it happened to over 200 images.  Two previous 'big trips' to multiple countries encountered no occurrences like this.

I cannot explain how this problem arose with the images (this is a 1 y/o iPhone 15 Pro, and a review of previous images from overseas travel shows no similar issues). But here's how I fixed it, using the wonderful 'exiftool' utility.
I copied the originals to a new folder for safety. I then ran this command to correct five incorrect EXIF and XMP fields (EXIF:CreateDate, EXIF:DateTimeOriginal, EXIF:ModifyDate and also XMP:CreateDate, XMP:ModifyDate)
exiftool -overwrite_original -P -if "$EXIF:OffsetTime eq '-07:00'" "-AllDates+=09:00" *.jpg

(this adds 9 hours to all the date fields. Note that 'AllDates' is an exiftools 'shorthand' for the three exif date fields, and then exiftools further applies the change to any identically named non-exif tags)
I then ran this command to correct the one field XMP-photoshop, for completeness:
exiftool -overwrite_original -P -if "$EXIF:OffsetTime eq '-07:00'" "-XMP-photoshop:DateCreated+=09:00" *.jpg

Finally, I ran this command to correct the three 'OffsetTime' fields (EXIF:OffsetTime, EXIF:OffsetTimeOriginal, EXIF:OffsetTimeDigitized)
exiftool -overwrite_original -P -if "$EXIF:OffsetTime eq '-07:00'" "-OffsetTime*=+02:00" *.jpg

This simply changes the three OffsetTime* fields from -07:00 to +02:00. (the '' in OffsetTime' is another 'shorthand' in exiftool to refer to all three OffsetTime fields).
It would have been better to construct the correct date/time values by adding the correct offset (+2 hours) to the image's 'GPS' time/date value; that would have been a more generalized solution but getting that to work exceeded my exiftool skill set, so my solution is somewhat 'hard-coded' based on my particular corruption; all my corrupted images had an offset of -7, and an intended offset of +2, so adding +9 was a simple way to correct that situation for me.
The other answer provided here - using Apple Photos on the Mac - may correct ALL these corrupted fields, but since I don't have Apple Photos at my disposal, I chose to use exiftool (I have an iPhone camera but use Windows and Google Photos for my main image handling tasks).
Note there is a great command in exiftool to show you ALL date fields in an image file:
exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s img_1840.jpg
For one of my images, it showed this:
[System]        FileModifyDate                  : 2024:10:12 16:13:31-07:00
[System]        FileAccessDate                  : 2024:10:12 21:40:20-07:00
[System]        FileCreateDate                  : 2024:10:12 12:35:13-07:00
[IFD0]          ModifyDate                      : 2024:09:20 03:59:05
[ExifIFD]       DateTimeOriginal                : 2024:09:20 03:59:05
[ExifIFD]       CreateDate                      : 2024:09:20 03:59:05
[ExifIFD]       OffsetTime                      : -07:00
[ExifIFD]       OffsetTimeOriginal              : -07:00
[ExifIFD]       OffsetTimeDigitized             : -07:00
[ExifIFD]       SubSecTimeOriginal              : 363
[ExifIFD]       SubSecTimeDigitized             : 363
[GPS]           GPSTimeStamp                    : 10:59:04
[GPS]           GPSDateStamp                    : 2024:09:20
[XMP-xmp]       CreateDate                      : 2024:09:20 03:59:05
[XMP-xmp]       ModifyDate                      : 2024:09:20 03:59:05
[XMP-photoshop] DateCreated                     : 2024:09:20 03:59:05
[ICC-header]    ProfileDateTime                 : 2022:01:01 00:00:00
[Composite]     SubSecCreateDate                : 2024:09:20 03:59:05.363-07:00
[Composite]     SubSecDateTimeOriginal          : 2024:09:20 03:59:05.363-07:00
[Composite]     SubSecModifyDate                : 2024:09:20 03:59:05-07:00
[Composite]     GPSDateTime                     : 2024:09:20 10:59:04Z

I'm curious to know if Apple Photos fixes ALL of the corrupted fields. I also don't know how you would find the 'bad' images in Apple Photos in the first place because it somehow manages to sort the images correctly even though the metadata is wrong. In my case, the image corruption was very random so there weren't any obvious 'blocks' of bad images.

Since multiple people have experienced this, Apple Support would be a great place to confirm they don’t have an active investigation into this.

If you’re taking photos only from Apple’s app (and not using other apps to save to the “camera coll”) and you have one solid group with the wrong time, it could be a bad update for time zone.
If the above is your problem (OP has a more complex failure as shown by edits to the post) consider checking a sample photo on upcoming trips when you are waiting for your bags, checking into a hotel, etc... so that your time zone is updated to save the correct data when you capture the images.

Either way, Apple's Photos app on macOS lets you bulk update time stamps by the correct offset to accommodate people not having cellular service update the device time zone correctly when you travel around the globe.
Select the first and last image from the trip and use the Image > Change Date and Time menu item. There's even a handy pin to move locations and know the offset if you're not sure.

Or if you have items that came from others in the range, making an album to select all the items needing change should be efficient to patch things up. You'll likely need that based on the some good, some bad pattern you ended up with. So sorry you have to clean this up, hopefully the memories will all be enhanced once the times are set correctly.

Hmm, so exit tool and windows have them wrong, but macOS and iOS show them in order?

exif tool simply 'reports' what it sees, and shows the obviously wrong Offset times and DateTime fields.. Despite the obviously wrong EXIF data, both Google Photos and Apple Photos (on the iPhone) 'sort' the images in the correct order.  Windows File Mgr can sort by Date modified, date taken, Date Created, etc. I don't have a recent MacOS device to play with.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I just learned that Google Photos uses the GPS TimeStamp in conjunction with the GPS coordinates to determine timezone and thus 'local time' - it pays no attention to the 'Offset' data in the file.  This explains why Google Photos sorted all the images perfectly despite the bad data. I can imagine the Apple Photos does the same.
